# When "and" is used two different ways in a sentence . . .

Tags: punctuation, commas, conjunctions, oxford-comma

I know it is not correct to put a comma before "and" if the subject is the same but I feel like I should do so if "and" appears earlier in the sentence like this:

He was convicted of murder and human trafficking, and jailed.

or

She set aside the condom and lubricant, and turned her face away.

Should I keep the comma or drop it? I know I could reword it to use two separate sentences and avoid the issue altogether, but this happens to me a lot and I want to face the issue head-on.

Answer (score 1):

What you have are two examples of so-called *garden paths*, sentences that are arranged to mislead your reader into making the wrong parse.  In the first sentence, your reader might expect a **third crime** instead of a consequence:

> He was convicted of murder and human trafficking and **driving on an
>   expired license**.

In the second sentence, your reader might expect a **third item** to set aside instead of an action:

> She set aside the condom and lubricant and **the plastic sex toy**.

The general rule is that a comma separates two independent clauses, not two verb phrases in a compound predicate, so you wouldn't write

> convicted of murder, and jailed

or

> She set aside her feelings, and turned her face away.

But a good manual of style will allow exceptions which are necessary in the opinion of a careful author. As the *Chicago Manual of Style* notes

> Punctuation should be governed by its function, which is to make the
>   author's meaning clear, to promote ease of reading, and in varying
>   degrees to contribute to the author's style.

Comment: Would the following be acceptable: 1. "He was convicted and jailed of murder and human trafficking." 2. "She turned her face away and set aside the condom and lubricant." Just wondering whether these are "poor" sentences because *and* is repeated twice.

Comment: 1. is not OK because *jail* does not license *of*.  You can say *He was convicted of and jailed for murder.* 2. means something different: turning before setting aside.  You original has setting aside first.  I think you can prevent a garden path for 1. with *He was convicted of murder and human trafficking and then jailed for his crimes.* The adverb presages the verb. (In the US, *imprisoned* would be preferred to *jailed*.)

Comment: Aah, *jailed for* of course. How stupid of me not to have realized that. No. 2. has changed the sequence of actions, but otherwise it would be acceptable. Am I correct?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, I think the rephrased 2. is fine, at least grammatically.  And I don't think the repetition of *and* makes the sentences poor.  For me, the first *and* in the rephrased 2. connects two crimes, and the second *and* emphasizes the connection between crime and punishment. But that's just a style consideration.  *De gustibus* and all that.  By the way, thanks for your help in migrating 322857.